# The new DNA study showing that we have two DNA codes and not only one unique code

Tags: dna, genetic-code

I am looking for a study that i read maybe 2-3 years ago that i cant find at the moment.

Scientist has always believed that humans only have one unique DNA code that makes us who we are, but a couple of years ago scientist found that we actually have two DNA codes, something that the scientists called mysterious and that this changed what we always have belived regarding humans uniqe DNA code that makes us who we are, now this was not true anymore with this new finding, since we have two codes which means that who we are could be more complex and not only be information stored in one DNA code. I cant find this study when i look for it on google, do you know which study i am speaking of? i would like to find it again, so that i can see if there is any updates by the scientists, and i also think it is extremely interesting and don't want it to get lost, i forgot to save it in favorites before.

Comment: This is not about [epigenetics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epigenetics) is it? Defenitely know for longer than 2-3 years but otherwise might fit what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you are referring to so-called "duons" (dual-use codons) [discovered by Stergachis *et al.*](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3967546/). This paper was published a bit more than six years ago. A recent paper within the last 2-3 years references duons implicated in [photosynthesis](https://www.pnas.org/content/115/8/1931).

Duons essentially extend the idea that conserved coding DNA encodes proteins, but can in fact also preferentially encode sites which bind [transcription factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcription_factor), at the same time. DNA can code proteins as well as code that controls regulatory regions, which in turn are switches that control how proteins get made.

Disclaimer: I am a contributing author in the linked *Science* paper.

Comment: Thanks but thats not it, im talking about a whole new DNA code beside our orgiginal discovered DNA code. The author speaks about our individual traits not necessarily being defined by our original DNA code and the whole thing being mysterious.

Comment: I'm lost. But I hope you find the answer you're looking for.